# Drag start delay not working for mobile devices

Tags: angular, angular8

I added a timeout function to change the dragEnabled value on my div. The idea is to start dragging after the user holds down mouse or holds on mobile for 0.3s. Everything works fine on PC but on mobile the drag doesn't start for some reason.

Can I work around this somehow?

```
<div #jobElement dnd-draggable (onDragStart)="onDragStart(jobs, $event)" (onDragEnd)="onDragEnd(jobs, $event)" (drag)="onDrag($event)"
         (pointerdown)="highlightJob(jobElement, jobs, $event)" (pointerup)="unhighlightJob(jobs)" (pointermove)="clearHighlightTimer()"
         [dragEnabled]="jobs.jobs.length < 2 && !shiftService.shiftLocked && jobs.draggable"
         [dragData]="['job', jobs, this.shift.unspecifiedJobs, this.shift.notRequiredJobs, this.shift.cancelledJobs]">
      </div>
```

Logic for changing dragEnabled:

```
highlightJob(jobElement, jobs, event) {
    if (jobs.jobs.length < 2) {
      this.highlightTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        jobs.draggable = true;
      }, this.dragDelay);
    }
  }

  unhighlightJob(jobs) {
    this.clearHighlightTimer();
    jobs.draggable = false;
  }

  clearHighlightTimer() {
    if (this.highlightTimer) {
      clearTimeout(this.highlightTimer);
    }
  }
```